# How to connect firebase database to an android studio project where i am using sharedpreference

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, sharedpreferences

So i am using sharedpreference in a voter app and i want to reset counts so that users can vote again next time

So there are 10 counters with 10 textview
I want at perticular time that counts at zero meaning i want to reset that counts but at perticular time.
So how can i connect this to firebase so that everytime users will vote vote also increase in firebase database and at perticular time like 12 am i will manually update that value on zero so users can bote again for the same thing.

Main activity

```
<public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
     TextView tv10;  
     Button btn10;  
     int  counter10 = 0;  
     u/Override  
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
     super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );  
    setContentView ( R.layout.*activity\_main* );  


    btn10 = findViewById ( R.id.*btn10* );  
     tv10 =findViewById ( R.id.*tv10* );  
     counter10= test10.*loadtotalfrompreftest10*  ( this );  
     tv10.setText ( Integer.*toString* ( counter10 ) );  


    btn10.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {  
     u/Override  
     public void onClick(View v) {  
     counter10++;  
     test10.*saveTotalInPreftest10* ( getApplicationContext (),counter10 );  
     tv10.setText ( Integer.*toString* ( counter10 ) );  
     Toast.*makeText* ( getApplicationContext (),"you clicked button 
    10",Toast.*LENGTH\_SHORT* ).show ();  


    }  
    } );  


       }  
    }
```

Class file

```
 private static final String *MY\_PREFERENCE\_NAME* = "package com.example.voting";  
     private static final String *PREF\_TOTAL\_KEY10* = "pref\_total\_key10";  


    public  static void saveTotalInPreftest10(Context context, int test10total){  


    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences ( 
       *MY\_PREFERENCE\_NAME*,Context.*MODE\_PRIVATE* );  
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit ();  
     editor.putInt ( *PREF\_TOTAL\_KEY10*,test10total );  
     editor.apply ();  


       }  
     public static int loadtotalfrompreftest10 (Context context){  
     SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences (  *MY\_PREFERENCE\_NAME*,Context.*MODE\_PRIVATE* );  
     return pref.getInt ( *PREF\_TOTAL\_KEY10*,0 );  
    }  


    }
```

Xml file

```
<?*xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"*?>*  
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
         android:layout\_width="match\_parent"  
         android:layout\_height="match\_parent"  
         tools:context=".MainActivity">  


       <Button  
     android:id="@+id/btn10"  
     android:layout\_width="178dp"  
     android:layout\_height="113dp"  
     android:text="Button"  
     app:layout\_constraintBottom\_toBottomOf="parent"  
     app:layout\_constraintEnd\_toEndOf="parent"  
     app:layout\_constraintStart\_toStartOf="parent"  
     app:layout\_constraintTop\_toTopOf="parent" />      


       <TextView  
     android:id="@+id/tv10"  
     android:layout\_width="119dp"  
     android:layout\_height="88dp"  
     android:text="0"  
     app:layout\_constraintBottom\_toTopOf="@+id/btn10"  
     app:layout\_constraintEnd\_toEndOf="parent"  
     app:layout\_constraintStart\_toStartOf="parent"  
     app:layout\_constraintTop\_toTopOf="parent" />  
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```